# Sum products of properties over array of objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this object array:

```
0:
  id: "123123"
  cost: "100"
  quantity: "2"
1:
  id: "112233"
  cost: "100"
  quantity: "5"
```

I want each array to calculate cost * quantity and then add them all for the total price.

How do I do this using vue.js? I already made one but I was using vanilla js and I'm wondering if there's an easier way to do this using vue.js.

Comment: "*I already made one [...] and I'm wondering if there's an easier way [...]*" – Then please update your question with your current code. You could use your existing code with a Vue.js computed property for instance.

Comment: Just use your JS implementation. Vue is only a presentation library, it's not going to offer any more efficient ways to manipulate arrays etc

Comment: Are you using this array inside a vue component? If so then you can share the component to see how you are getting the array and where you are saving it

Comment: `{{ item.cost * item.quantity }}`, assuming you are using `v-for`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const src = [{id:"123123",cost:"100",quantity:"2"},{id:"112233",cost:"100",quantity:"5"}],

     result = src.reduce((r, {cost,quantity}) => r+= cost*quantity, 0)
     
console.log(result)
```